# Oracle Sqldeveloper : command line "Connection Name" creation

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Can you please help me to create "Connection Name" using command line for SQL developer. I am looking for command to create connection name

Comment: Which CLI, sdsql or SQLcl?

Comment: If sdsql, you create the connection/name in the GUI and then reference that connection name when using sdsql calls

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly.. I am trying to run sdcli command using Jenkins, so when i run i am getting "Connection Name not found". The user name for local and Jenkins are different user. Please do let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Throwing error for the existing connection name in Jenkins, but it works fine on local command prompt, so thinking to create connection name and then using the corresponding connection name in jenkins

Comment: The connections are stored with the os user...so make sure they're the same

Comment: is there any other option to create connection without using GUI. existing connections are stored via service account, I will be running Jenkins using my id.

Comment: Copy those files over to the Jenkins os user appdata folder ... Should be ok if on the same machine, otherwise the passwords are encrypted and won't work on a different machine

Comment: thanks, it worked for me, but not sure how to make your comment as the answer. @thatjeffsmith